# Require children of certain type in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a custom React Component for a Dropdown menu. The structure I had in mind to use this component was something among the lines of

```js
<Dropdown>
  <DropdownTrigger> // The button that triggers the dropdown to open or close
    open me
  </DropdownTrigger>
  <DropdownButton> // A button inside the dropdown
    Option 1
  </DropdownButton>
</Dropdown>
```

The way I wanted to implement this, is by having the `Dropdown` component check if there is a `DropdownTrigger` component in its children, and if there is, clone the given `DropdownTrigger` component using `React.cloneElement` and pass an `onClick` property, that calls a state update on the `Dropdown` component.

Small code snippet of `Dropdown.js`

```
  import DropdownTrigger from './DropdownTrigger';

  _toggleDropdown () {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }


  _renderTriggerButton () {
    const triggerChild = this.props.children.find(child => child.type === DropdownTrigger);
    return React.cloneElement(triggerChild, {
      ...triggerChild.props,
      onClick: () => this._toggleDropdown()
    });
  }
```

Is this a correct approach and if so, what would be the cleanest/nicest possible way to validate the `Dropdown` component has a `DropdownTrigger` as child. As this means a developer always has to include a `DropdownTrigger` as child of the `Dropdown` component, I would like to have a nice way to tell developer they should pass a `<TriggerButton>` component as child of the dropdown.

I'm also open for suggestions about changes in the structure. Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, it looks like maybe you could just specify the properties of the `<DropdownTrigger>` to the `<Dropdown>`, rather than requiring that one be passed as a child.

Comment: I tried that initially, but I want to be able to use custom components inside my `<DropdownTrigger>`. Maybe I could have a `triggerButton` property on `<Dropdown>`, which expects a React component? That way I won't have to loop the children.

Answer (score 4):

**Use [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to pass additional properties to child components. In combination with [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) you can do exactly what you want.**

---

It could be something along the lines...

```
import React from 'react';
import DropdownTrigger from './DropdownTrigger';

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
          const additionalProps = {}
          // add additional props if it's the DropdownTrigger
          if (child instanceof DropdownTrigger) {
            additionalProps.toggleDropDown = () => { } ...
          }

          return React.cloneElement(child, additionalProps);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```